# Extra Attributes while login with facebook using OAuth and Devise Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

i've been searching for a way to do the following and I haven't succeded yet.

I have already implemented Facebook Login with my app, but i am looking for a way to ask the user for some extra attributes that are not provided by Facebook (Like home address for example).

I tried redirecting the user to the edit_user_registration page once he is logged in for the first time, but I can't add the new attributes because the user won't know his password due to the fact that is provided by Facebook and its encripted.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Can you please post the error or the stack from your server log just after when you are trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First override `Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController` controller. Add a method for Facebook connection in which you have to do two things. First if the user is already on your system, this method should log the user in directly.

Second if the user is new, you should build a user object, extract the parameters you need from Facebook and update this user object with these parameters. After that you should render a page where the user can input their own password and add the extra information you need.

**omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    user = User.find_by_fb_token(token)
    if user.present?
      sign_in user, event: :authentication
    else
      @user = User.new(**Facebook parameters**)
      render 'devise/registrations/after_social_connection'
    end
  end
end
```

In the `after_social_connection` view, add a form for `@user` where you will have all attributes from Facebook prepopulated. Do not forget to add `:password` and `:password_confirmation` fields for the user to be able to have a password on your own application. In this view you can add whatever attributes you like the user to input.

Since you are using Rails 4, you also need to override devise parameters sanitizer (strong parameters) to be able to input extra fields in a form. This can be done in the application controller (the lazy way)

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    def configure_permitted_parameters
       devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :email. :name, :biography, :profile_picture) }
    end
end
```

For further reading
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: Do I need to add any changes to the routes? Cause I am trying to implement this right now and I keep getting Template is missing error.  
---
Missing template users/omniauth_callbacks/facebook, devise/omniauth_callbacks/facebook, devise/facebook, application/facebook with {:locale=>[:es], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/**/******/app/views" * "/home/**/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.3.0/app/views" * "/home/**/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.0/app/views"

Comment: `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations", :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks", :passwords => "passwords" }` This is how routes should be configured in devise for omniauth. You need no further action.